# Wrapping an element with Html.ActionLink..?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I'd like to wrap a span with an action link because I'm adhering to an existing CSS theme. It doesn't look like any of `Html.ActionLink`'s constructors allow for this. Possible solutions:

1. A way to achieve this with existing helper?
2. Derive & override ActionLink with new custom html helper?

If #2 is the only way I have two questions.

1. When I right click ActionLink and hit go to definition I only see the constructor signature not that actual code body. How do I see the original function body? I don't see anything on MSDN either
2. The above will more or less tell me, but, how to generate action url dynamically?c

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action(...) %>"><span></span></a>
```