# How to create custom MVC3 ActionLink method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to put span element inside ActionLink MVC3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518109/how-to-put-span-element-inside-actionlink-mvc3)

How to create custom MVC3 ActionLink method that generates this output:

```
<li>
    <a href="/Home/ControllerName" data-ajax-update="#scroll" 
     data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-method="GET" 
     data-ajax-loading="#progress" data-ajax="true">

     <span>LinkText</span> // this span generated inside <a>

    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Please don't repeat same question which you only have asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518109/how-to-put-span-element-inside-actionlink-mvc3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You either create a new extension method that returns an `MvcHtmlString` object that you put together yourself *(mind the html encoding, though)*, our you create a partial view that you can render when you need it, so you don't have to create HTML through code.

```
public static class MyHtmlExtensions {
    public static MvcHtmlString MyActionLink(this HtmlHelper html, string action, string controller, string ajaxUpdateId, string spanText) {
         var url = UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl("~/" + controller + "/" + action);
         var result = new StringBuilder();
         result.Append("<a href=\"");
         result.Append(HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(url));
         result.Append("\" data-ajax-update=\"");
         result.Append(HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode("#" + ajaxUpdateId));
         // ... and so on

         return new MvcHtmlString(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create a custom HTML helper for razor. That way you can render custom HTML (including your requirement of span tag) for your link. This helper exttention method must return a MvcHtmlString object.

One example for [creating HTML helper](http://develoq.net/2011/how-to-create-custom-html-helpers-for-asp-net-mvc-3-and-razor-view-engine/) can be found here.